# Database down in Microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, microservices

I have a microservice name order-creation-service(used Java) which creates food orders .Orders are stored in SQL database.Lets say DB is experiencing outage/down for 1 hour.But I dont want to stop my order creation process as this would result in financial loss.What is the way to handle this failure scenario ?

Comment: A backup database.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  will REDIS work?Backup DB wont work lets if DB server is down itself

Comment: I mean a backup database on a different machine, not simply a different dbms. If your main database is down you fire up a copy that runs on another machine and point your application to that machine while you fix the primary one (which then, of course, you'll have to bring up to date)

Comment: You need to archive orders somewhere reliable, so Redis, since is a cache, doesn't fulfill the scope. A secondary database, as suggested by @SaveSoil would. Another option would be to use cloud native databases (such as dynamo db for AWS) which should never go down

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are asking how to increase availability for a database.

There are several approaches to dial with such issues - most of them are some types of replication (sync, async or semi-sync). I wouldn't go with adding a cache or even switching your database technology. Adding a cache layer is another system to manage - and that will add consistency challenges to your system, not something anyone wants to deal with.

As a first step, I would look into a synchronous replication with manual failover. This is easiest way to increase availability.

After manual stuff is done, you should look into automatic failover. There are plenty of solutions (depending on what db you are using). As an example, I recommend to look into GitHub's infrastructure - which is based on Orchestrator: https://github.blog/2016-12-08-orchestrator-github/ This way you reduce the down time by a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no avaiable DB in which to save incoming orders, then fundamentally the order service has to do one of two things:

- accept orders but don't save them in the DB
- reject orders

Note that if you take the "accept but don't save" approach, the DB can't guarantee to always have every order that's ever been accepted (even if there's a bulletproof process for getting the orders which were accepted during the DB's downtime into the DB, that process will have some latency).

You could for instance, save orders into a different (unlikely to become unavailable at the same time as the primary) DB.  Note that this requires anything which queries the primary DB to be aware that it will either get an incomplete view or be able to query the failover DB as well as the primary (some queries may become massively more difficult and/or inefficient by introducing the failover DB as the primary DB).

It's far more often than not effectively impossible to take an application that hasn't been designed for high-availability and make it highly-available (if availability is defined as "being able to fulfill its functional requirements", not just "answers a health-check ping").  Choosing datastores which are themselves highly-available and being willing to design around their limitations (e.g. some queries may not be practical) and adopting other patterns throughout your architecture may make it easier to implement a highly-available application.